# Writing a comment to a file in VSS 6.0 without using checkin method

Tags: c#, visual-sourcesafe

I am writing an app that connects to VSS through c#, allows you to checkin and checkout files, but I use the move() method a lot and am wondering if there's anyway to add a comment to this moved file without having to check it out and check it back in, as these files are usually +2gb and it takes a lot of extra time to do that. So far what I have is using the VSSVersion comment property, but its a get only prop. Anything I am missing here or is there really no way to write a comment to a file?

Also, moving away from VSS is not exactly an option right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the msdn website, IVSSVersions `string Comment { get; }` is only a 'get' property. The only way to do this would be to manually go into VSS and do these changes. Since microsoft does not seem to support VSS anymore. The only work around method would be to write to a txt file labeled 'comments' each time you call the move method. Hope this helps!

Comment: Seems like a viable workout until we move to a new source control